# How do I use Grip?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

I am in the Konpa Ruins, and entered a room where I got a Grip Crystal, so apparently I can use Grip now with an Earth Adept.

Problem is, I don't see it in my list of Psynergy options.

How do I make it so I can use Grip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure a Venus Adept has it equipped first.

Then, look for thin/long pole/spire-shaped things and "grip" them.

Comment: I don't see grip listed under my psynergy skills even though I have the crystal. :(

Comment: Only Matthew or Himi (being Venus Adepts) can use Grip (when you equip them with the Crystal). You can also use Grip to grasp small objects from a distance, like with Catch.